# nServicebus web server deployment

Tags: deployment, web, nservicebus

I have a basic nServicebus 3.2.0 setup with a web application endpoint and a dll endpoint. It is very similar to the async web app example that nservicebus distributes. Everything runs when it is all on my local machine.

I am trying to deploy the web application to a web server and reference the dll endpoint that is running on my local machine. My "messageEndpointMappings" web.config entry references my local machine name (endpoint ="server@MyMachineName").

It currently won't send the messages to the dll enpoint on my machine from the web app on the server. Do I need to do anything extra on the server to get this all to work?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Also, it doesn't throw any exceptions when I run it.

Comment: The message from the web app is sitting in a MSMQ outgoing queue on the server.

Comment: i figured it out. I had to use the ip address in my config instead of the machine name.

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, some other things that you need to ensure are: distributed transaction service is running on all machines with endpoints, msmq is running on all machines with endpoints. You can check the event log in the application section for msmq error messages.

Comment: Glad to hear! Can you add the above as the answer to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out. I had to use the ip address in my config instead of the machine name.

In case it helps anyone else, some other things that you need to ensure are: distributed transaction service is running on all machines with endpoints, msmq is running on all machines with endpoints. You can check the event log in the application section for msmq error messages.